# Drawing large images for ipad

Tags: image, ipad, drawing

I am developing an application for viewing images.
I used the example of PhotoScroller Apple to implement this application.
In my application I want to be able to draw on the image.

I had the idea to put a UIView on top with transparent background and draw the lines via touch events. This solution has become very slow because the generated images are very large, around 3700x2000 pixels.

I also tried a solution with the example of Apple GLPaint that uses OpenGL, but it has a size limitation of 2048x2048 pixels.

Anyone have any idea or example of how I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try and tile your image.

One option is using CATiledLayer. Have a look at [this short tutorial](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/).

Or you could try and use `CGContextDrawTiledImage` to get your stuff done. Possibly [this post from S.O. could help you getting started](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679925/how-can-i-use-cgcontextdrawtiledimage-to-tile-an-image).

Comment: i want to draw lines with finger on image. the image is loaded fine, but the drawing with finger is not good. it is slow.
I created a UIView and get de points of touches events and draw lines between points, but it is slow.

Comment: don't you think that slowness could be related to image size?

Comment: Yes, i do!
So. i want to draw images, zooming and save it.
To view the original image i used CATiledLayer. To drawing, i'm using an other view with transparent background and drawing lines on it.
I want an app like a windows paint app.
I think i'm not being clear.

Comment: Maybe you can use tiled image as your target for drawing also, not only for the base image?