# how do I tile a 1px vertical line as a UIColor

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uicolor

So I have a 1px width with 50px height of a .png file and I want to tile this horizontally in a UISegmentedButton, so I did:

```
[segmentedCtrl setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-gradient-brown.png"]]];
```

All I got is however a black color. Why is this and how to do this correctly? Here's the 1px that I have, if it helps to clarify my point

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try with core graphics methods to tile, look at this code from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679925/how-can-i-use-cgcontextdrawtiledimage-to-tile-an-image),

```
CGSize imageViewSize = imageView.bounds.size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageViewSize);
CGContextRef imageContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextDrawTiledImage(imageContext, (CGRect){ CGPointZero, imageViewSize }, tileImage);
UIImage *finishedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

It creates a titled image. you can set image as the background to your UIcontrol.

EDIT:
 `tintColor` is base for creating default gradient of segment control. So setting brown gradient image as tint color gives you black gradient. 
To set gradient colors,

- subclass `uisegmentcontrol` class and override `drawRect` method.
- Use `backgroundImage` and set proper image insets.

Comment: I don't have a black png.. it's a brown png, look carefully